Setup Google Auth ASP.NET Core 8 working on localhost and fails on IIS/Public domain
This is my first post in this platform as I've been fighting for the past few days on how to make the Login with google working on my public hosted ASP.NET Core 8 razor application.
I have created the test app with built-in individual account identity and I just wanted that the user can also use the external "Login with Google Button". So far all is set app in Google Console for test and live env.
After clearing the browser cookies, I can log in to my gmail account and accept the consent, but the website gets stuck at https://accounts.google.de/accounts/SetSID with a black screen.
I have checked the log files on the server and here is the error:

AuthenticationScheme: Identity.External signed out.
dbug:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[9]
AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was not authenticated.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google.GoogleHandler[1]
HandleChallenge with Location: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=123456789-p2pr7k9u3csr3bf2oi4q371l4mknlvt4.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.com%2Fsignin-google&scope=openid%20profile%20email&state=CfDJ8HUuH7wf9pVAhDa0nCG4_wseg8oTlXJuzTRe_dE1HRsf1R8cKjznSnl9vnyveqjflvztW3yEN3HrJj6frbJTZfZn4sfve7cUGXpV7Trw_xeZ3Cf_14SO-gVIQWbQ5XBQ5VP_CjWNiMYXV49nEzWeP6YXih5xbepcR9IeWE1rRqZQoAhI3D3FdYj-4xwFMopbt9_oVpnIjtkRoQNU1kQbTBmiQjx9eizAt09RuLrllN9LGBGEeViSGuS0V_naAJDcxxov_log_24iT0ADfmDrhQE2AAZwIpfOfIK4W38ATrldTmJ_oGQCO20JJKcaN9c6bQ;
and Set-Cookie:
.AspNetCore.Correlation.eaYOjJgaDjsQetrVB8NMjSVlYXUIwCsHVyTO6wRvk9M=N;
expires=Sun, 25 Aug 2024 15:21:14 GMT; path=/signin-google; secure;
samesite=none; httponly.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google.GoogleHandler[12]
AuthenticationScheme: Google was challenged.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google.GoogleHandler[4]
Error from RemoteAuthentication: The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 60 seconds elapsing..
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationFailureException: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 60 seconds elapsing.
System.TimeoutException: A task was canceled.
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.HandleFailure(Exception e, Boolean telemetryStarted, HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationTokenSource cts, CancellationToken cancellationToken, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts)   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthHandler1.ExchangeCodeAsync(OAuthCodeExchangeContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthHandler1.HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync()   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler1.HandleRequestAsync()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.g__Awaited|10_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[9]
AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was not authenticated.
dbug:  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[9]
AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was not authenticated.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Application is shutting down...

And this is my Program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddHttpClient("GoogleHandler")
       .ConfigureHttpClient(client =>
       {
           client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10); // Increase timeout to 2 minutes
       });

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(o =>
{
    o.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.DefaultForbidScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddGoogle(options =>
{
    options.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
    options.Scope.Add("profile");
    options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-google");
    options.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
    options.RemoteAuthenticationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60*10);
});

builder.Services.ConfigureExternalCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
});

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
});



if (builder.Environment.IsProduction())
{
    builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
            .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"\homepages\72\f1017982336\www\_keys"));

    builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
            .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"\homepages\23\f1017982336\www\_keys"))
            .ProtectKeysWithDpapi();
}


builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
       policyBuilder =>
        {
            policyBuilder.WithOrigins("mydomain.com", "localhost:7195")
                         .AllowAnyHeader()
                         .AllowAnyMethod()
                         .AllowCredentials();
        });
});


builder.Services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
    options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
    options.KnownProxies.Clear();
});

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();


var app = builder.Build();
app.UseForwardedHeaders();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();   
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();

I have tried to override the HttpClient timeout to 10 minutes => same behavior.
I have set ngrok but didn't get it working when the request is back to my website. It points always to my localhost.
Tried Cookie.SameSite: Lax/Unspecified/None/Strict => the same error
In web.config file I have st the maximum URL length to 4096
<requestLimits maxUrl="4096" maxQueryString="4096" maxAllowedContentLength="10485760"/>

I have tried to downgrade Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google to version 7 => the same.
